# div cutted when no vertical scroll in browser

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

I have the fallowing property:

```
div{width:300px;}
```

and everything is fine because there is a vertical scroll(with a width of 17px).

but when I have the same div in a place where there is no vertical scroll there is a void (cause there is no 17px vertical scrollbar of course)

My question is: what is the correct way to approach this problem?

something like this logic maybe?

```
if !scrollbarY 
then div.width=div.width + scrollbarY 
else div.width
```

or maybe placing a verticalscroll not having the need?

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet as I'm finding it hard to envisage exactly what is happening - how the div fits within its parent and how the parent's width is ascertained.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `div {overflow: scroll;}`, scrollbar sections will show whether a scrollbar is needed or not (or void as you say). If you set `div {overflow: auto;}`, it will only show the scrollbar sections when necessary. Run the code snippet to see an example of both.

```css
.one,
.two,
.three {
  width:300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid pink
}

.one {
  overflow: scroll
}
.two,
.three {
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  jlnka sdflj knasd
</div>
<div class="two">
  jlnkasdf ljknas dflkjn.
</div>
<div class="three">
  jlnkasdf ljknas dflkjn asdflkj nasdflk jnasdfl kjnasdf lkjnasd flkjnas dflkjnas dflkjnas dflkjnas dfkljnas dfkljnas dlfkjnas
</div>
```

Comment: the perfect solution for my issue could be : when there is no sidebar the whole div should margin rigth the div dimension. when there is a sidebar, the div should remain the same

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're saying: "should margin rigth the div dimension. when there is a sidebar, the div should remain the same"

Comment: correct! thanks for correct the sentence

Comment: @MaykelContrerasCamacho I didn't change anything, I just copied the part of your sentence that I didn't understand. Not sure what you mean in that sentence.

Comment: let me explain myself...the main div we are talking about has a fixed width. if there is a vertical scroll (that verticalScrollWidth=17px) is a longitud added. that affect the interface. Of course I can make a diferent div for every view (I am about to do that), but I was wonder if there is a better approach out there...uh oh...I haven t say that the div has aligned-center elements inside, that depends  on the distance from the center to the rigth. maybe a pic will be better for me to explain this.